# XSLT drop down does not call javascript function

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

i used this dropdown in xslt to call a javascript method onChange event but nothing happens at all when i change the value of the list!

```
    <select id="selectedSession"  onchange="loadSessionSections(this.value)">
        <xsl:for-each select="page/sessions/session">
            <option>
                <xsl:attribute name="value">
                        <xsl:value-of select="./SessionId" />
                </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="./SessionName" />
            </option>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </select>
```

and placed the function as follows:

```
<script language="javascript">
  alert("__________-");

function loadSessionSections(var sessionId){
    alert(sessionId);
    }
</script>
```

Note: the first alert() in the above block doesn't called also !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your JavaScript console for the syntax error in your function declaration. You've got a `var` keyword where it shouldn't be.